# How Can i Solve This Problem in Flutter I want To Write With This Version Of Packages

Tags: flutter, dart, package, version

[image: This Is Issue]

> How Can I solve It I Can Not Enter Flutter pub Get Commaned Line

Comment: can you include full pubspec.yaml, I think it is having duplicate packages on dependencies

Comment: Looks like you have duplicated packages added. Can you add more info on how your pubspec.yaml looks and what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple entries in pubspec.yaml for same plugins.
Remove all the lines showing red squiggles underline.

Comment: remove those package you mean this ?\

Comment: yes. all the packages which has red line underneath.

Comment: okay and should i do then i want those packges with thie version